# Add Description in Dropdown List Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

In a spreadsheet, I saw a dropdown list using data validation as below. As it shows, the value is **numerical**, namely, 0 or 1. They act as a switch and will be used in formula. However, there are additional accompanying description to each number (**note the description doesn't make the cell text; the cell still is a number**). Does anyone know how to add these description, please? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like a technique I sometimes use, using custom number formatting to display additional information without introducing messy text to be parsed elsewhere. Eg "£1,234 net profit" or ""72 unique customers".

If you look at the number format for that cell i suspect you will see something like:

```
0": Net of tax";;0": Gross of tax";@
```

(the important parts are distinguishing between positive and zero values, it seems negative will not be an option so may be omitted (hence ;; with nothing between them)

Comment: Thank you AdamV. That is exactly what I found when looking at the format.